# RefreshApex doesn't update my existing account

Tags: apex, javascript

```
openModal(event) {
    const row = event.target.closest('tr');
    this.siret = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent;
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(this.companies.data); // Convert the array to a JSON string
    const details = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    this.foundRecord = details.find((record) => record.siret === this.siret);
    console.log(this.foundRecord.siret);
    getAccount({ siret: this.foundRecord.siret })
        .then(result => {
            this.exists = result;
            console.log("Is existent : ", this.exists);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
        });
    getExistAccount({ siret: this.foundRecord.siret })
        .then(result => {
            this.existAccount = result;
            if(this.existAccount){
                console.log("Account : ", this.existAccount);
            }else{
                console.log("Account does not exist")
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
        });
    this.isModalCrAccount = true;
}
closeModal() {
    this.isModalOpen = false;
    this.isModalCrAccount = false;
}
handleChange(event) {
    // Display field-level errors and disable button if a name field is empty.
    if (!event.target.value) {
        event.target.reportValidity();
        this.disabled = true;
    } else {
        this.disabled = false;
    }
}
createAccount() {
    const fields = {};
    fields[NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.name;
    fields[SIREN.fieldApiName] = this.foundRecord.siren;
    fields[SIRET.fieldApiName] = this.foundRecord.siret;
    fields[NIC.fieldApiName] = this.foundRecord.nic;
    fields[NumEmployeesField.fieldApiName] = this.numEmp;
    fields[Categorie.fieldApiName] = this.catEnt;

    const recordInput = { apiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };
    createRecord(recordInput)
        .then((account) => {
            this.accountId = account.id;
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: "Success",
                    message: "Account created",
                    variant: "success",
                }),
            );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: "Error creating record",
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: "error",
                }),
            );
        });
}

updateAccount(){
    // const allValid = [...this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input")].reduce(
    //     (validSoFar, inputFields) => {
    //         inputFields.reportValidity();
    //         return validSoFar && inputFields.checkValidity();
    //     },
    //     true,
    // );
        const fields = {};
        fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.existAccount.Id;
        fields[ACCOUNTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.template.querySelector(
            "[data-field='AccountName']",
        ).value;
        fields[NumEmployeesField.fieldApiName] = this.template.querySelector(
            "[data-field='Employees']",
        ).value;
        fields[SIREN.fieldApiName] = this.existAccount.siren;
        fields[SIRET.fieldApiName] = this.existAccount.siret;
        fields[NIC.fieldApiName] = this.existAccount.nic;
        fields[Categorie.fieldApiName] = this.template.querySelector(
            "[data-field='category']",
        ).value;

        const recordInput = { fields };

        updateRecord(recordInput)
            .then(() => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: "Success",
                        message: "Account updated",
                        variant: "success",
                    }),
                );
                return refreshApex(this.existAccount);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: "Error Updating record",
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: "error",
                    }),
                );
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`refreshApex` only works on `@wire` methods. Since `getExistAccount` is called imperatively, where you then set the value `this.existAccount = result`, you'll have to call the code imperatively. You'll probably want to pull the call out to its own function so you can call it from both `openModal` and `updateAccount`.

Comment: I think it would help to link to and quote from [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-result-caching.html).

Comment: Hello Thanks you  i'll check your suggestions .